monitor oracle services health using spring boot and jmx?
I have a weblogic domain that contain a Admin server , and a cluster of osb managed servers that host an application exposing a set of APIs, I use the the em console to access to the service health monitoring by doing this" targes --> soa --> service bus --> service health"
now I want to automat this to monitored it from my local machine, one of the approaches suggests using JMX, therefor I followed the oracle doc here
and created a spring boot project, the doc says that I need to add those jars to my class path:
weblogic.jar
oracle.servicebus.configfwk.jar
xervicebus-common.jar
servicebus.jar

I have managed to download them from the server, then tried the code in the doc,
what I am facing right now is that those jars do not appear to have all the nodules needed for the code ex:
import com.bea.wli.monitoring.*;
import com.bea.wli.sb.util.Refs;
import weblogic.management.jmx.MBeanServerInvocationHandler;

I can not either find the .monitoring or .sb or the weblogic, although I am following the doc dedicated to the same version which is 12.2.1.4.0,
any suggestions about that, or is there a easier way to monitor the services health...thanks in advance.
Note: I am really new to jmx, there any details would help.
